# How can I crop a photo to this shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, mask, crop

I have very little experience with photoshop and I'm trying to crop a photo to a particular shape for a project. This is the shape I need:

[image]

From what I can understand I can do this with a mask but I've no idea how. Is anyone able to explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Clipping Mask**

- Put the *Photo Layer* on top of the *Shape Layer* and holding on <kbd>Alt</kbd> click in the middle of the two layers

[image]

**Mask**

- At the *Photo Layer*, load the *Shape Layer* transparency selection and
  click the **Mask Icon** at the bottom of the **Layers Panel**

[image]